# jQuery preventdefault() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Here is my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhyZk/1/).

Actually I am trying to validate a text field before it submits.
I want to show the `errormsg_box` if the text field is empty, if it's not then submit a form,
but here it is not working
Here is my script:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {

    var text_val = $('#emailid').val();
    alert(text_val);
    if (text_val != ' ') {
        $('.errormsg_box').show();
        return false;
        event.preventdefault();
    }
    else if (text_val != '') {
        $('.errormsg_box').hide();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: First, JavaScript is case sensitive language. It should be `event.preventDefault()`. Next, `return false` overlaps with `preventDefault`.

Comment: For validation, please use the jQuery validate plugin. it is far more flexible and specific for validating form fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($.trim(text_val) === "") {
    return false;
    // Or
    event.preventDefault(); // event.preventdefault()
                            // javascript is case sensitive.
}
```

**Full code:**

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    var text_val = $('#emailid').val();

    if ($.trim(text_val) === "") {
        $('.errormsg_box').show();
        return false;
    }
    else 
        $('.errormsg_box').hide();
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hhyZk/6/)

If you want to validte the text is a valid email address:

```
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if (!regex.test($.trim(text_val)))
    ... Error
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hhyZk/13/)

Comment: +1 you are the only (except me `:)`) who got that there are `return false` and `preventDefault` together. Plus trimming is a good practice.

Comment: but ' ' = show msg box and '' = hide, so trimming is combining the two to '' which is always hide.

Comment: @gdoron The full code is indeed better, but does no email validation as Suresh Pattu is trying to do.

Comment: @JPHellemons. I didn't see q request like that in his question. anyway it can be done easily with a regex

Comment: When we are using `jQuery` (I use the latest v1 series from google) we can check whether a value is email address or not by simply set input type to `email`. `<input type='email' name='whatever'/>`. It will automatically prevent the form submission if the given value is not in an email format.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {    
    var text_val = $.trim($('#emailid').val()); // $.trim() for remove space
    if (!text_val) { // check for empty
        $('.errormsg_box').show();
        return false;
        //or
        //event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/hhyZk/9/)**

Comment: You might want to comment on what you changed.

Comment: You prevent the default no matter what is the value.

Comment: hi your script is not working. I tried in jsfiddle here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/hhyZk/3/

Comment: Hi it is not submitting the form after i entered the email address why? here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hhyZk/7/

Comment: @SureshPattu check the demo now

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** this might be a better solution:

```
<input id="emailid" class="required email" />
```

and use the jQuery validation plugin:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

```
$("#form").validate();
```

so something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").submit(function () {
        var container = $('errormsg_box');

        var validator = $("#form").validate({
            errorContainer: container,
            errorLabelContainer: $("ul", container),
            ignore: ":not(:visible)", 
            wrapper: 'li',
            rules: {
                emailid: { required: true, email: true }
            },
            messages: {
                emailid: "The e-mailaddress is invalid!"
            }
        });
        if ($("#form").valid()) {
            alert('ok nice!');
        }      
    });
});
```